# node/express download base64 image

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to download base64 data using node-express.As a result,image is not correctly,only show a black line!Actual, i just want to download a qr-code!!!

```js
router.get('/download-qrcode', function (req, res, next) {
  var buf = req.query.image;
  buf = buf.split(',');
  buf = new Buffer(buf[1], 'base64');
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'image/png');
  res.setHeader('Content-Length', buf.length);
  res.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=qrcode.png");
  res.end(buf, 'binary');
});
```

req.query.image value like 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgA.....'

Please advise ...Thanks for everyone..

Comment: Was it passed entirely? Have you checked the `req.query.image.length`? Browsers and webservers tend to have limits on how long your url can be.

Comment: I got the length in chrome devtools....url.length:12602

Comment: Well, check `req.query.image.length` in code. And compare that it matches the encoded image length.

Comment: I got the length in firefox devtools....url.length = 12602 and when I received  the req.query.image in routes ,got req.query.image.length = 12602...It's also got the error image! By other way, when I tried in chrome. I got the url and req.query.image.length = 19682....so what should I do...I am troubled

Comment: And what is the real length of the base64-encoded image?

Comment: How to get it real length?

Comment: Uhm, where does the url come from? Who generates it?

Comment: I used qrcode.js to generates it!

Comment: I'm not following. qrcode.js generates qrcodes. Your whole question currently needs the following details: what generates the url? what is the original length of the image?

Comment: ok, I'm wrong! thank you every much!~